# Parsing an RSS item that has a colon in the tag with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, rss

I'm trying to parse the info from an RSS feed that has this tag structure:

```
<dc:subject>foo bar</dc:subject>
```

using the built in Ruby RSS library. Obviously, doing `item.dc:subject` is throwing errors, but I can't figure out any way to pull out that info. Is there any way to get this to work? Or is it possible with a different RSS library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags with ':' in them are really XML tags with a namespace. I never had good results using the RSS module because the feed formats often don't meet the specs, causing the module to give up. I highly recommend using Nokogiri to parse the feed, whether it is RDF, RSS or ATOM.

Nokogiri has the ability to use XPath accessors or CSS accessors, and, both support namespaces. The last two lines would be equivalent:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://somehost.com/rss_feed'))
doc.at('//dc:subject').text
doc.at('dc|subject').text
```

When dealing with namespaces you'll need to add the declaration to the XPath accessor:

```
doc.at('//dc:subject', 'dc' => 'link to dc declaration')
```

[See the "Namespaces" section](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) for more info.

Without a URL or a better sample I can't do more, but that should get you pointed in a better direction.

A couple years I wrote a big RSS aggregator for my job using Nokogiri that handled RDF, RSS and ATOM. Ruby's RSS library wasn't up to the task but Nokogiri was awesome.

If you don't want to roll your own, [Paul Dix's Feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) is a good gem for processing feeds.

Comment: Expanding on this idea, the gem 'arrogance' is built on nokogiri, and makes parsing a feed as simple as passing in the feed URL and manipulating the array of posts returned. Rubygems: https://rubygems.org/gems/arrogance

Comment: I'll take a look at it some time. When I wrote my aggregator there was nothing I found that handled the wide range of totally messed up feeds I encountered.

Comment: Yup, Arrogance discovers the tags for you, and sets them as [:title] [:author] [:link] [:description] and [:date] no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

The [RSS](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html) module seems to have the ability to do those XML namespace attributes, i.e. `<dc:date>` like this:

`feed.items.each do |item|
    puts "Date: #{item.dc_date}"
end`

Answer (score -1):

I think `item['dc:subject']` might work.

Comment: Yeah, the rss parser is completely ignoring those tags that it doesn't recognize, so they aren't even making it into the `item` object. Bummer. How would I grab the `<item>` elements with `libxml`? The xml tree looks like this: `<rdf:RDF><channel></channel><item></item><item></item></rdf:RDF>`, but doing `doc.find("//rdf:RDF/item").each` isn't finding anything.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into Nokogiri instead of libxml. Nokogiri is very robust and well supported.